# drill down data from csv file (Highcharts)

Tags: csv, charts, highcharts, line, drilldown

I currently have a highchart that takes values from a csv file and displays them in a line chart, which works fine. 
However, I'm looking to add drill down data for the points in my chart. The drill down values need to be taken from a file ( preferably the same csv file but can be another one as well). I'm unsure how to format my csv file and change my code to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far https://jsfiddle.net/g8mdLLLp/

```
      $.get('http://localhost/Pre/myfile.csv', function(data) {
            // Split the lines
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                var items = line.split(',');

                // header line containes categories
                if (lineNo == 0) {
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                    });
                }

                // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
                else {
                    var series = {
                        data: []
                    };
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo == 0) {
                            series.name = item;
                        } else {
                            series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                        }
                    });

                    options.series.push(series);

                }

            });

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
```

My csv file looks like:

Results

ValueOne,11,22,16,10,11,33,03,19,13,02,15

ValueTwo,23,34,32,23,32,16,30,21,34,21,31

ValueThree,86,76,79,77,91,74,81,81,75,63,64

ValueFour,3,16,13,15,27,11,24,21,19,13,26

ValueFive 1,77,61,64,71,71,75,63,63,74,64,71

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, how do you know which value should drilldown to which value? You need to somehow pass on information like "from value 10, I drilldown to values 5,4,1".

Comment: The data at this point is irrelevant its all dummy data, I just don't know how to format the csv file to include the drill down data and how do I incorporate that into the code itself? unfortunately I've been stuck on this for awhile..

Comment: I think this is really hard to include such info in one file. I mean preprocessing data later to fit Highcharts format will be hard to handle. I would suggest several files, which later will be loaded on demand, like in Highcharts [demo](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown) ("Async drilldown"). Something like: `ValueOne,11,filename_1`, `ValueTwo,23,filename_2`. And when user drilldowns, load respective file and add to the chart. How does it sound? If you achieve that, then I would suggest trying to include all information in one file?

Comment: yeah I wouldn't mind using a few files, how would I go about making the points clickable and pointing to a specific file though? I really appreciate your help by the way!

Comment: alternatively, is it possible to add an onclick to each point , and load a new csv file with the drill down data when clicked?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my point. I think you didn't open my link to the API. There is a demo with asynchronous (kind of) demo. See the config object. And in `drilldown` event you should call new `$.get()` to get new data.

Comment: And do I keep my csv file in the same format as its in now just with different values?

Comment: Yes, that is my idea. I mean, top level will need extra information (like `filename`), and all other files won't have that column. And in `drilldown` event pickup filename, load file and set data as in the demo.